# Change text in google Pay giftcard

Tags: php, api, google-pay

When creating a giftcard in google pay via API I everytime see the wording "Geschenkkarte":
[image]

My goal is to change this wording to "Guthabenkarte". Is there a way to do this? I tried every string I could find in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/giftcardclass
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If this renders as HTML in the browser, then maybe try and inspect the element, to see if there’s any class names on or around it, that match any property name mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Unfortunatelly the documentation does not mention anything about this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/gift-cards/design#card-title the card title cannot be edited.

You can ask for this as a feature request see https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/contact/instore_merchant_support?visit_id=637189488311884461-3625029917&rd=1